# Why is object not getting saved to HazelCast IMap?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

## Background

I am new to Hazelcast. I'm currently working on an internal tool that uses Hazelcast to cache our data.

## Problem

The HazelCast `IMap` has a `String` key & `HashMap<K, V>` value.

We are having an issue with this tool, where inputting an updated `HashMap` object with `put()` into the `IMap` does not update the `HashMap` object, refer to sample code below. The `V` in `HashMap<K, V>` is what gets updated.

### Code Structure

In our main code, we have the following:

```java
main() {
    updateTableStatus(...);
    // other business logic 
    updateTableStatus(...);
}
```

The `updateTableStatus` code updates the `IMap`:

```java
updateTableStatus(...) {
    hazelcastInstance.getMap("String").put(K, V);
}
```

After running the app in debug mode, it seems that the first `updateTableStatus` does not update the `HashMap` object, only the second `updateTableStatus`.

The tool is a SpringBoot application, where the HazelcastInstance object is defined as follows:

```java
@Autowired
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;
```

I understand that objects saved to the Hazelcast `IMap` need to be serializable, but it seems that Hazelcast already has optimized the serialization for `HashMap` objects as per [link](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/serialization/serialization#data-types-with-built-in-serialization).

## My Research/Effort To Debug The Problem

I'm not quite sure what other avenues to explore with regards to updating objects in a Hazelcast `IMap`, these were the StackOverflow articles I referred to:

- [SO Article #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833498/hazelcast-imap-put-method-when-key-is-already-present)
- [SO Article #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828569/weird-hazelcat-imapput-behaviour)
- [SO Article #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372287/hazelcast-imap-delete-put-and-then-get-immediately-for-a-specific-key-returns-o)

I think Article #3 is the closest to what I'm asking, but his post had no answers, so I'm not sure how else to proceed.

If there is any other missing pieces of information I could provide about the project / Hazelcast setup, please let me know! I'm still new & learning :)

I appreciate any responses & other people's understanding :)

Comment: i couldn't get the point. maybe there is some typo, I think you may add a listener to Imap and see really updated or not. For each operation, (add/update/delete/etc) listener is triggered and can see old/new data.

Comment: @newuserua_ext hey, i insert updated `HashMap` objects into `IMap` with `put()` & retrieve them later, but based on the debug output, the `HashMap` objects in `IMap` didn't actually get updated

Comment: What is the configuration of hazelcast? Are you using client side caching?

Comment: @waffledood, let's also try `map.replace` method and see is there any change on map value.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez hey, i pasted the configuration [here](https://textdoc.co/IwUx56QVXFWCrNPi), but doesn't seem like there's client-side caching, perhaps i'm wrong (edit -- my vpn doesn't allow me to access text-sharing sites, will get back to you)

Comment: @newuserua_ext hey `map.replace()` doesn't work. if i insert the same `HashMap` object (after modifying it) into `IMap`, it gets saved to the Hazelcast cache, but if i insert a new `HashMap` object into `IMap`, it doesn't get saved. any idea why? bpth of the `HashMap` objects were inserted into the same key

Comment: +1 to the Map Listener suggestion. What's also worth trying is making the value an integer/string/long, as this'll help confirm if the problem is with updates or with updates to a collection. If still stuck, the Hazelcast Community Slack channel might get you more interactive help

Comment: hi all, just wanted to update that i think i've found a solution, we were using the `HashMap` initially retrieved from `IMap` at the start of the application's run, instead of actively retrieving `HashMap` from `IMap`. hence we were referring to a `HashMap` that was never getting updated